# How do you compare two data frames of different shapes and output the result as column level side by side comparison

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

df1:

```
       fname    lname    age
0      Chris    Potter   23
1      John     Doe      32
2      Jane     vw       25
3      will     Tesla    45
```

df2:

```
      fname     lname    age
0     George    Potter   23
1     John      Hall     32
2     Jane      vw       27
```

Tried with Merge function but it is giving the row wise results.

```
fname  RESULT fname           lname  RESULT  lname           age RESULT  age 
Chris  FAIL  George             Potter   PASS  Potter      23  PASS      23
John     PASS John               Doe    FAIL     Hall       32  PASS      32
Jane     PASS Jane               vw      FAIL   Tesla       25  FAIL      27
will    FAIL  NAN               Tesla      FAIL  NAN        45   FAIL    NAN
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are these pandas DataFrames? Something else?

Comment: These are pandas dataframes

Comment: combined_df = source.merge(target,  how="outer", indicator=True)
    print(combined_df)
    diff = combined_df.loc[lambda x: x['_merge'] != 'both']
    diff.rename(columns={'_merge': 'validation'}, inplace=True)